# Python constructor not being called, error

Tags: python, discord

working on a Discord Bot currently to practice my skills.

Working on a Blackjack system for my Casino Cog, and I assume I'm just missing something about the language as I'm not well-versed in Python yet.

My intention is to let the Casino Cog accept the command from the user to start a game of blackjack, and then it will create a game and add it to its own list of on-going blackjack games. For some reason or another, the constructor/init is error-ing out in my command handler

Does anyone know a reason this could happen? Am I not allowed to create an object synchronously in an async method? Do I have to use asyncio to wrap this in a wait... I'm quite lost

```
@commands.command(name='blackjack')
  async def bj(self, pCtx, amount:int):
    if amount < 0:
      await pCtx.send("Can't bet a negative amount")
      return
    ID = pCtx.message.author.id
    user = await self.bot.db.koomdata.find_one({'_uid':int(ID)})
    if user['_currency'] < amount:
      await pCtx.send("You don't have enough money to gamble")
      return
    print('pre')
    game = cogs.blackjack.BlackjackGame(self.bot, pCtx.message, int(amount))
    print('post')
    self.bjSessions.append(game)
```

We never reach the 'post' print in the above line, I've tried breakpointing in VS Code and the program just stops at that line, so I'm assuming there's some error with the data I'm passing in. But as far as I can tell the **init** function takes all of those parameters

```
def __init__(self, bot, message, amount:int):
  self.bot = bot
  self.message = message
  self.amount = amount
  self.player = message.author.id
  self.playerhand = []
  self.dealerhand =  [] 
  self.dealerStopped = False
```

Edit: File Structure:

```
secrets.py
bot.py
-> cogs
    -> casino.py
    -> blackjack.py
```

Error: module 'cogs' has no attribute 'blackjack'

Further edit: does python not let me import python files from other directories? Does 'cogs.blackjack' not work when I'm trying to import something? Cause that's really sad if I have to put everything top level

### Thanks for any help guys,

Comment: Could you please post your File Structure and the full error?
The best thing would be to post your whole File too :D (but optional)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yes I'll update with the file structure and I'll have to only include parts as the full file is a few hundred lines :)

Answer (score -1):

```
  async def bj(self, pCtx, amount:int):
if amount < 0:
  await pCtx.send("Can't bet a negative amount")
  return
ID = pCtx.message.author.id
user = await self.bot.db.koomdata.find_one({'_uid':int(ID)})
if user['_currency'] < amount:
  await pCtx.send("You don't have enough money to gamble")
  return
game = cogs.blackjack.BlackjackGame(self.bot, pCtx.message, int(amount))
self.bjSessions.append(game)


  def __init__(self, bot, message, amount:int):
self.bot = bot
self.message = message
self.amount = amount
self.player = message.author.id
self.playerhand = []
self.dealerhand =  [] 
self.dealerStopped = False



def deal(self):
self.playerhand = []
self.dealerhand = []
self.playerhand.append(random.choice(cards))
self.dealerhand.append(random.choice(cards))
self.playerhand.append(random.choice(cards))
self.dealerhand.append(random.choice(cards))
self.playerhand.append(random.choice(cards))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).